# Use single backslash in helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am using helm template to generate a input command for a shell container where i need to escape the  single quote. I am able to achieve using `["f'\''first","second"]` but when i try to generate with helm i am facing the below issue.

template.yaml

```
---
example: {{- .Values.items | toJson | nindent 2 }}
```

values.yaml

```
---
items: ["f'\''first", "second"]
```

Current output

```
---
example:
  ["f'''first","second"]
```

Expected output

```
---
example:
  ["f'\''first","second"]
```

If i use `["f'\\''first","second"]`  i get `["f'\\''first","second"]` whereas i need just one backslash

Answer (score 0):

It's an artifact of the quoting.

```
$: cat values.yaml templates/template.yaml
---
items: [ "f'\''first", "s'\\''second", o'\''other ]

---
asJSON       : {{- .Values.items | toJson | nindent 2 }}
asYAML       : {{- .Values.items | toYaml | nindent 2 }}
raw-quoted   : {{  .Values.items | quote              }}
just-raw     : {{  .Values.items                      }}
individually : {{- range $ndx, $v := .Values.items    }}
 {{ $ndx }}: {{ $v }}
 {{- end }}

$: helm template .
---
# Source: foo/templates/template.yaml
asJSON       :
  ["f'''first","s'\\''second","o'\\''other"]
asYAML       :
  - f'''first
  - s'\''second
  - o'\''other
raw-quoted   : "[f'''first s'\\''second o'\\''other]"
just-raw     : [f'''first s'\''second o'\''other]
individually :
 0: f'''first
 1: s'\''second
 2: o'\''other
```

Note the output of each version using each method.
What you want is exactly what you are getting with two backslashes, but when you try to show it, it's changing the output for "clarity". Pay special attention to the actual result in the `individually` output of the correctly formatted *second* value (index 1).